# CSS hover not works on a table cell if it has a specific background color

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I alredy set a `:hover` effect on the rows of the table using CSS.
The only problem is the hover effect doesn't work, if a table cell has a specific background color, e.g. green. In the sample code this means the 3rd column doesn't change the background color from green (resp. red) to `#96c7ef` as soon as you move the mouse over it. (It's ok, that the first row also doesn't change the background color. This is intentionally skipped using `<thead>`.) On the other cells, that don't have any background color, the hover works.

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./basic.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
        <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
        <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

basic.css

```
.multidata td,.multidata th {
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}

.tdX {
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tdY {
    background-color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The hover effect also has the same behaviour, if the style declaration of the two cell (tdX, tdY) is specified as inline style. I specified !important, but nothing changes.

What is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say just tr hover then you can just change tr background, but td has background and over the tr. So you should say hovered tr's td. So just add

```
.multidata  tbody>tr:hover td {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}
```

```css
.multidata td,.multidata th {
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata  tbody>tr:hover td {
    background-color:#96c7ef!important;
}
.tdX {
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tdY {
    background-color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
        <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
        <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome :) your missing only that u changing tr background which is backend of td and your td has background. So u should say hovered tr's td background

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the background color of the rows on hover should also be applied to those cells which *do* already have a background color (i.e. override this), you can extend the selector for the hover rule to also apply to the cells:

```
.multidata tbody>tr:hover,
.multidata tbody>tr:hover td {
  background-color: #96c7ef!important;
}
```

Actually it's even sufficient to simply use the second line (i.e. the one including the cells) in the selector, since this will apply to *all*  cells of that row:

```
.multidata tbody>tr:hover td {
  background-color: #96c7ef!important;
}
```

Here in your full code:

```css
.multidata td,
.multidata th {
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata tbody>tr:hover td {
  background-color: #96c7ef!important;
}

.tdX {
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tdY {
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
    <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
    <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
    <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
    <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better style the TDs of the hovered TR using

.multidata tbody>tr:hover td{
    background-color:#96c7ef
}

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to put `<tr>` inside `<tbody>`

something like this

```
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
        <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
        <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.multidata td,.multidata th {
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}

.multidata tr:hover td {
    background-color:#96c7ef;
}

.tdX {
    background-color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.tdY {
    background-color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./basic.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<table class="multidata" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="change_on_hover">
            <th style="width: 10%">ID</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Name</th>
            <th style="width: 10%">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>1</i></td>
        <td class="td1" style="color:grey"><i>First</i></td>
        <td class="tdX" align="center"><b>Disabled</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="change_on_hover">
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>2</i></td>
        <td class="td2" style="color:grey"><i>Second</i></td>
        <td class="tdY" align="center"><b>Active</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```